# Why is `&mut &foo` valid but `&mut a_ref_to_foo` is invalid?

Tags: rust

In the following example, `t1` compiles but `t2` does not.

Is there anything special about `&mut &stream`? I don't think `Deref` kicks in.

```
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn t1() {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1").unwrap();
    let a = &mut &stream;
}

fn t2(stream: &TcpStream) {
    let a = &mut stream;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0757b5f5810ff917b93a45924db9f00e&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
9  | fn t2(stream: &TcpStream) {
   |       ------ use `mut stream` here to make mutable
10 |     let a = &mut stream;
   |                  ^^^^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
&mut &foo
```

This does two things - it creates a temporary value of type `&Foo`, then creates another temporary of type `&mut &Foo`.

```
let a_ref_to_foo = &foo;
&mut a_ref_to_foo
```

This also creates a temporary of type `&mut &Foo`, but to something that is observable via the variable binding `a_ref_to_foo`, **not** another temporary.

The problem is the same as this example:

```
// Works
String::new().clear();

// Doesn't work
let s = String::new();
s.clear();
```

When you have a temporary value, you have ownership over it which includes treating it as mutable. Once it's been assigned to a binding, the *binding* has ownership and you must indicate that it's allowed to be mutated or not.

Comment: `let a_ref_to_foo = &foo;` should read `let mut a_ref_to_foo = &foo;`. Suggested edit was rejected.

Comment: @red75prime no. The second example is intended to mirror OPs case. Adding a `mut` would make the code compile, negating the whole point of the example. Presumably OP already knows how to fix it (the compiler error message says as much) and is asking what the difference is.

Comment: ah, I missed `&mut a_ref_to_foo` in the question's title. The code in the question doesn't contain it, so I decided that you introduced it just to explain how temporary values work. I'm sorry for false positive.